How to create multi-channel tif image with python
I have set of microscopy images, each subset has two channels which I need to merge into one .tif image (Each merged image should contain two channels)
import cv2 as cv

im1 = cv.imread('/img1.tif', cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
im2 = cv.imread('/img1.tif', cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

im3 = im1 + im2


cv.imwrite('img3.tif', im3)


That way it creates a file with one channel, but I'd like to get 16-bit .tif image with two channels that can be viewed separately in ImageJ, for example. Which way it can be corrected?

You're going to have to explain what you mean with "combine", because there's a number of different results you might want, and without explaining which one you want, there is no answer here yet.

If you wanted to generate a TIFF file containing a "stack" of images, you don't need tifffile. You can use OpenCV's own function cv.imwritemulti():
import cv2 as cv

im1 = cv.imread('img1.tif', cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
im2 = cv.imread('img1.tif', cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

im3 = [im1, im2] # a stack of two

cv.imwritemulti('img3.tif', im3)


Olga
Maybe using tifffile will be here a solution
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import tifffile as tiff 

im1 = cv.imread('/img1.tif', cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
im2 = cv.imread('/img1.tif', cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

merged_image = np.stack((im1, im2), axis=0)
print("Image shape:", merged_image.shape)

tiff.imwrite('img3.tif', merged_image, imagej=True)



